# Basic Question - Why are additional characters appearing when converting a CSV to a text file?

Tags: excel

This is a basic question that I cannot find the answer for.  I have a CSV file that is adding a quotation marks to one of my values when I open it as a text.  I've not encountered this before.  Any advice?

Comment: Show us a screenshot or something, we cant guess what you're seeing.

Answer (score 2):

In the `CSV` format, quotations are sometimes used around certain items, especially if it has special characters in it like commas. Otherwise, programs will think that the comma inside that item splits the column.

```
name, age, location
Amy, 49, "Phoenix, AZ"
Amy, 49, Phoenix, AZ
```

It would be difficult to tell if `Phoenix` and `AZ` are two separate columns without quotations (e.g. 3 columns versus 4 columns in the example above). So some programs will add in quotation marks to resolve that confusion.